# Helix QAC++ project creation by cli

Tags: static-analysis, qa-c

it is possible to create a project Helix QAC++ by qacli?
now, i create an empty  project by QAC++ GUI and then i use qacli sync in order to syncronize and populate the project with all the cpp file. is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Assuming your installation of QAC is fairly recent, instructions for creating a QAC project are likely to be on page 19 or 20 of the main Helix QAC user manual.

Specifically:

```
qacli admin --qaf-project <directory> --qaf-project-config --cct <file> --acf
<file> --rcf <file>
```

`<directory>` should ideally be the root folder of your source. The PRQA folder and related *prqaproject.xml* files will be created within.

From there, you just need your existing `qacli sync` with your specific parameters to add the files.